# Transform Web.config Hibernate configuration VS 2012

Tags: c#, hibernate, visual-studio-2012, web-config

I have Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">{old_connection}</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate</property>
      <property name="show_sql">false</property>
      <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

I apply a transformation. Web.Release.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
               xmlns:hib="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <hib:hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <hib:session-factory>
      <hib:property xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="connection.connection_string">{new_connection}</hib:property>
    </hib:session-factory>
  </hib:hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

Run in VS2012 in Release, the transformation does not occur. The string is not replaced.
In what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation does not happen because the element names differs from your baseline `Web.config`. If you remove the `hib` namespace, transformation will take place.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="connection.connection_string">{new_connection}</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

Another thing to note. If your current configuration is `Release` and you are running your application through `Visual Studio`, the server will point to the root of your project. In the root, you will have `Web.config`, `Web.Debug.config` and `Web.Release.config` and the server will pick-up the usual configuration file, without the transformation (ie `Web.config`).

Comment: web.config not changed, with namespaces is no problem. But you were right in that transformation is occurring in the publication. It worked when I just posted.